# problem with primefaces library (jsf)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i am new to primeface.

i have tried to test an example of primefaces about  tag as in its documentation,

this is my jsf page code:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui" prefix="p"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

 <head>

  <base href="<%=basePath%>">

  <title>My JSP 'index.jsp' starting page</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <f:view>
   <h:form>
    <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{counterBean.count}" />
    <p:poll actionListener="#{counterBean.increment}" update="txt_count" />
   </h:form>
  </f:view>
 </body>


</html>
```

and this is my backbean code:
[code]

```
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;


public class CounterBean {
private int count;
public void increment(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
count++;
}
//getters and setters
public int getCount() {
 return count;
}
public void setCount(int count) {
 this.count = count;
}
}
```

but when i tried to running it. i got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@ed32c4 not expected type.  Expected: javax.faces.component.UIForm.  Perhaps you're missing a tag?
 com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.FormTag.setProperties(FormTag.java:199)
 javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.findComponent(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:586)
 javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.doStartTag(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1070)
 com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:273)
 org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005fform_005f0(index_jsp.java:120)
 org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:93)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
 com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:428)
 com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.executePageToBuildView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:444)
 com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:116)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:106)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:144)
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:245)
```

what is wrong? how can i solve it? i am using tomcat 6
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
>   Component javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@ed32c4 not expected type. 
>   Expected: javax.faces.component.UIForm. Perhaps you're missing a tag?
> ```

The exception suggests that you've a `h:form` somewhere in the page which is *not* been placed inside a `f:view`.

Since your code example looks fine (apart from the ugly *scriptlets*), you're likely not running the code you think you're running. Redo the build and deployment and check if you did everything correctly.

Comment: thanks for your reply it has been fixed. but i have another problem
when my pages is loaded it says that "yahoo is not defined" and it does not work. i have defined resources servlet and <p:resources> but it does not work yet!

Comment: That's a new question. You need to post a new question. Don't forget to mark this answer accepted. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/faq (and don't forget to accept some of previous answers as well whenever applicable: http://stackoverflow.com/users/332289/arash)

Answer (score 1):

They [changed the uri](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1431) in version 3.
Use: `http://primefaces.org/ui`